# localization of hibernate bean validation messages using request locale

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jax-rs, bean-validation

I need to internationalize my springboot application by adding support for different languages for the hibernate bean validation errors. I have used both inbuilt javax constraints as well as custom messages. The requirement is to return the validation errors in the language code defined in the incoming json request.
The project details are :

- Java 8
- Gradle build
- Springboot 2.4.4
  I have added the ValidationMessages.properties files . I need to set the localresolver to the locale as per the "langguageCode" field received in the rest api json . So that the user gets the validation errors in his language .

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `javax constraints`. There is some annotation e.g `@NotEmpty @NotBlank` etc.
Each of these has field message which can receive any language message.
Also, You can create custom validation's annotation and custom validator for it where you can have any logic with any messages.

```
@NotEmpty(message = "foreign language message")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i have already implemented the validations using the annotations. The actual requirement is if I use a local resolver to set the locale for the error messages, how do I change the locale as per the field "lang" in the incoming json request ? Sorry for the low clarity in the post